# What is the connection between Oort clouds and dark matter and dark energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, earth, space

I have a research assignment that I can't seem to find much info about, because it's not a very discussed or well theorized topic which is what is the connection between Oort clouds and dark matter and energy, and why is it said that they are not real?

Comment: Well you're already beginning on a rough topic since the Oort cloud has never been observed and is only highly theoretical. I know of no connection between it and dark matter at all.

Comment: "why is it said that they are not real?" Which of the three nouns (Oort clouds, dark energy, dark matter) do you mean? They each have different arguments for/against their existence.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see any connection between the three concepts beyond the fact that they are all hypothetical entities whose existence is supported by indirect observations and inference, but which have not (as yet) been directly observed.

The existence of the Oort cloud is inferred from observations of long period comets; the existence of dark matter is inferred from observations of galactic rotation curves and relative velocities of galaxies within clusters; the existence of dark energy is inferred from observations of how the expansion rate of the universe has changed over time.

Of course, "hypothetical" is a status that can change. Quarks were hypothetical until they were directly observed at SLAC in 1968. Gravitational waves were hypothetical until they were directly observed at LIGO in 2015.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a large Oort cloud around most galaxies made up of left over matter after star formation. This could explain most of or all of the radial velocity curves observed for galaxies.
It might be possible to detect this with the JWST at far infrared  frequencies. Its 25 micron detection would have a peak dark matter detection temperature of about 100 deg abs Kelvin. Using the Alma submillimeter array which has a detection wavelength of .32 to 3.6 millimeter would have a peak dark matter temperature of only a few degrees absolute.